# Equivalent of DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES on linux?

Tags: linux, linker, ld

on OSX, the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable forces the dynamic linker to print out, at runtime, the external libraries as they are accessed. Is there an equivalent one on linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./binary_name
```

Or

```
ldd ./binary_name
```

Or

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ./binary_name
```

Latest example traces runtime, first two - reading ELF header, without program execution.

Comment: The last one does exactly what I need. Thanks.